# Does MySql support connection pooling for Java SE applications?

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling

From the examples that I have read and from the documentation on MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource at http://www.control.auc.dk/~04gr733/filer/javadoc-DB-driver/com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource.html it seems that Java SE applications cannot use connection pooling. Is this true? Can I get connection pooling to work for MySql?

Does the same go for PreparedStatement pooling?

UPDATE:
I came across the following from the MySQL website with regards to their connection pooling.

```
    /*
     * Create a JNDI Initial context to be able to
     *  lookup  the DataSource
     *
     * In production-level code, this should be cached as
     * an instance or static variable, as it can
     * be quite expensive to create a JNDI context.
     *
     * Note: This code only works when you are using servlets
     * or EJBs in a J2EE application server. If you are
     * using connection pooling in standalone Java code, you
     * will have to create/configure datasources using whatever
     * mechanisms your particular connection pooling library
     * provides.
     */
```

This is what has made me look at a way to get this right for a Java SE application. But re-re-reading it, it seems to me that they are making reference to the manner in which you obtain a reference to the datasource. Could I not use a dependency injection framework or manual insert a dependency on the datasource for my DAO object? I am going to give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some third party Connection Pool for JDBC such as:
[BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) , [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) or [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)

Comment: so that means that I have to roll my own?

Comment: @uriDium - I would not roll my own, but use a preexisting one. In the past using DB/2 I have instantiated a DataSource object and then called the getConnection from there and it worked just fine (same as what an application container does)

Answer (score 1):

The MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource won't do it itself, use something like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) for that, or look at the examples at the [SDN on Connection Pooling](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html).